# ASP.NET MembershipProvider - SQL Server vs. Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

There are several option for storing the users info when dealing with ASP.NET Membership providers. I would like to ask if they are comparable in terms of performance. Especially of `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` and `SqlMembershipProvider` if when there will be e.g. 100 000 users recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Both Providers can handle the workload. Question is if the infrastructure below can handle it. An AD-Server with 100.000 accounts should be big enough to handle it.

So, the real question in my eyes is, do you write the app for an intranet and want to provide SSO functionality? Then, by all means, go with ActiveDirectory!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unanswerable, as "performance" depends greatly upon many factors.. for instance, network speed, network latency, network saturation, the power of your AD server vs your SQL Server, the disk subsystems in use in either, etc...

There is no way to say one way or the other without thoroughly evaluating each environment, and even at that point, you should just benchmark each and determine what works best for you.

In most cases, though.. the decision between sql vs ad has nothing to do with performance, and has to do with the features offered by each.  I would strongly doubt you have 100,000 users in your active directory, as that would cost a millions of dollars in licensing costs.